# CSS, includes & images VS mod_rewrite, relative Paths and Base Dir

Tags: php, css, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

### What I want

- `http://example.com/index.php?lang=en&page=main`

  should look like `http://example.com/en/main`
- Images, includes and CSS should have relative paths
- Site should be still accessible with the original links (if **possible?**)

### What I have

I've read a lot about htaccess, mod_rewrite, BasePath etc. 
I tried many combinations but there's always a case that doesn't work.

Mostly the CSS isn't loaded (wrong path: `/en/style.css`) or the old formatted links don't work anymore.

**My current structure:**

```
/incl
  |incl1.php
  |incl2.php

/img
  |img1.png
  |img2.png

index.php
style.css
```

**My current .htaccess:**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [L,NC]
```

**My current site:**

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<base href="http://example.com/">
...
<img src="img/img1.png" />
...
<?php include('incl/incl1.php'); ?>
```

**My current CSS:**

```
background-image: url(img/img2.png);
```

**Edit: What' not working:**

The CSS and the favicon are not found. Probably because they are assumed at `/en/style.css`

### What I need

The correct combination of

- .htaccess

  - `RewriteBase` (**do I need that?** I didn't get better results by trying it)
  - `RewriteCond`
  - `RewriteRule`
- Site

  - `<base href="http://example.com/">` **OR** `<base href="/">` ?
  - `src="style.css"` **OR** `src="/style.cs"` ?
  - `<?php include('incl/incl1.php'); ?>` **OR** `<?php include('/incl/incl1.php'); ?>` ?
- CSS

  - `background-image: url(img/img2.png);` **OR** `background-image: url(/img/img2.png);` ?
- Should I put all my images and css in a `/static` subfolder? How do I use that?

Thank you a lot!

Comment: So what exactly is not working?

Comment: The CSS and the favicon are not found. Probably because they are assumed at `/en/style.css`.

Is it possible that I need to put a `/` prefix only to the relative paths in the `<head>`? Just tried that and it seems to work, but I still need to test everything. How is that possible? Why only in the head?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand that rewrite rules cannot fix `php include` since that happens inside PHP and control doesn't even come back to PHP for that.

Now to fix `css/js/images` best option is to use absolute links. If for some reason you canot then try adding this in your page's header: `<base href="/" />`.

However there is `mod_rewrie` way to fix those rules also.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# fix css/js/images link
RewriteRule ^[a-z]{2}/(.+?\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js))$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```